# Check if thousands of records exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Some info that might help:
I have a MySQL db that holds contact details about students(first names, surnames, emails etc).

Every now and then I receive a csv file with the updated contact details.

Due to some policy, the ONLY information that is unlikely to change is the email address so the MySQL and csv file will have in common the email address(unless we have a new entry).

What I need:
What I need to do is to find a way to check if the email addresses from the csv file(5000 records) exist in the MySQL database(200000 records).

I wrote a little python program that does this but it takes ages since it has to perform an sql query for each email address(that means 5000 queries in a table of 200000 records). Sometimes the connection is lost due to the long time of execution..

Actual question:

How should I query the database in order to avoid long times and improve performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise:

- Bulk load email csv in a table on your mysql Server (requires FILE Rights)
- perform a LEFT JOIN request between your email csv table & existing DB to check which email exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below steps and sql

e.g.

table1: csv data table as @dweeves suggested.

table2: your mysql table

matched

```
SELECT table1.email FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email
```

unmatched:

```
SELECT table1.email FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email 

WHERE table2.email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all csv data into a list and open a mysql reader.
Compare the list onto the data in mysql.

Or if you don't want to store it on list,
read it line by line and while reading the file compare it to mysql.